Repeating a pattern sample using ORB feature matching with Open CV
I am trying to take a wallpaper sample with repeating features and generalize the pattern on a larger canvas, by using ORB or SIFT feature matching to basically map the sample onto the edges of itself to expand the pattern. The underlying principle would be like stitching together a panorama, except the pattern is being stitched onto itself, completing any cut off features at the edges.
here is one example of the type image that I am attempting to use for this
here is a more complex pattern that I am also trying to use for this
For first example, I am trying to match the cutoff top spaceship with the full bottom spaceship so that the pattern continues beyond the original edge of the wallpaper.
I have had success using ORB and OpenCV to do simple operations like image stitching portions of the wallpaper back together to create a larger sample. But I haven't been able to take my full sample and use it to create a large pattern.
I have tried using ORB feature matching by comparing the center of the image to each edge of the periphery (see below). But I have been unsuccessful in getting the center image to then map onto the outside edges as a complete image afterwards.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to crop the center 90% of the image

def crop_center(image, crop_percentage=0.9):
    # Get dimensions of the original image
    width, height = image.size

    # Calculate dimensions for the cropped image
    new_width = int(width * crop_percentage)
    new_height = int(height * crop_percentage)
    
    # Calculate the coordinates for the cropping box (centered)
    left = (width - new_width) // 2
    top = (height - new_height) // 2
    right = (width + new_width) // 2
    bottom = (height + new_height) // 2
    
    # Crop the image
    return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

# Function to extract the outer 10% edges of the image

def extract_edges(image, edge_percentage=0.1):
    width, height = image.size

    # Calculate edge sizes
    edge_width = int(width * edge_percentage)
    edge_height = int(height * edge_percentage)
    
    # Extract the four edge regions
    edges = {
        "top": image.crop((0, 0, width, edge_height)),
        "bottom": image.crop((0, height - edge_height, width, height)),
        "left": image.crop((0, 0, edge_width, height)),
        "right": image.crop((width - edge_width, 0, width, height)),
    }
    
    return edges

# Function to perform ORB feature matching

def feature_match(cropped_img, edge_img):
    # Convert images to grayscale
    cropped_img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(cropped_img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    edge_img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(edge_img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Initialize ORB detector
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    
    # Detect keypoints and descriptors
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(cropped_img_gray, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(edge_img_gray, None)
    
    # Create a Brute Force Matcher
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    
    # Match descriptors
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    
    # Sort matches based on their distance (lower distance is better)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
    
    # Draw the top 10 matches
    matched_image = cv2.drawMatches(np.array(cropped_img), kp1, np.array(edge_img), kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=2)
    
    # Return the matched image
    return matched_image

# Function to display the images in a Colab notebook

def show_image(img, title="Image"):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

# Main function

def find_and_show_matches(image_path):
    # Open the original image
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    # Crop the center 90% of the image
    cropped_img = crop_center(img)
    
    # Extract edges (top, bottom, left, right) which represent the outer 10%
    edges = extract_edges(img)
    
    # Perform feature matching for each edge and visualize matches
    for edge_name, edge_img in edges.items():
        matched_img = feature_match(cropped_img, edge_img)
    
        # Display the matches using matplotlib
        show_image(matched_img, title=f"Matches with {edge_name} edge")


If you'd like more elaboration on the peak finding, please let me know. I'm just waiting to see if you're still interested in the question.

Ditch feature matching. Use autocorrelation via convolution.

First, I have to crop the borders off the one picture. It now looks like this:


# the usual imports
# read image

im = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

im = im.astype(np.float32)

im -= im.mean()
im /= im.std()

# this is convolution
spec = cv.dft(im)
multiplied = cv.mulSpectrums(spec, spec, 0, conjB=True)
convolved = cv.idft(multiplied)

# shift it for display
convolved = np.fft.fftshift(convolved)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(convolved, cmap='turbo')
plt.show()

After you have that, you "just" need to find the off-identity peaks. More on that below.
Second picture: you can see the repetition very clearly. Nice sharp peaks. The vertical tiling appears to have some slight X offset on top (4-7 pixels, explored manually), and the tiling isn't perfect (tiles appear stretched). There appears to be some faint horizontal tiling too. It's probably a combination of a repetition and some novelty.

First picture: (left) with the crop, the autocorrelation looks really nice. Not as sharp but definitely easy to handle. (right) Without the crop, it looks terrible. Those edges ruin the result. Getting anything out of that would be a chore.



Finding peaks... if this were 1-D, you could have used scipy.signal.find_peaks.
Peaks are nothing but local maxima of a certain "quality".
First you'd want to run a local maximum filter (grayscale dilation) to know the local maximum for any pixel. The shape and size of the filter kernel determines the minimum distance between local maxima.
Then you can compare for equality, even they're floats, to find those pixels that are local maxima. Note that such pixels, if they have the same value, may be neighbors or even have tiny space between them. This would violate the "minimum distance" you thought you just ensured with the dilation kernel.
On that mask, you'll want to run closing morphology once more, to link those instances up. Then you need connected components analysis, to find those blobs and perhaps get their centroid or center of the bounding box. Unless you want not literally connected results to stay separate. Then skip the closing morphology operation.
You can filter peaks by absolute magnitude, or by "prominence", which is their difference to a local median or local minimum.
So there, local maxima.

Thank you very much for this response. I hadn't used autocorrelation before, and this is a very helpful solution. I was able to run the code you provided to see the peaks. The other steps are meant to filter out off-identity peaks, correct? I run a local maximum filter (grayscale dilation) with something like cv.dilate. I am using this to create a mask and then running a closing morphology cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) then doing connected component analysis with something like cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats.

My follow up question would be, how would I go about using the peak coordinates to map the features onto themselves and tile the pattern? Thanks again for your help.

the peaks tell you the pitch/stride. then you'll have to figure out the phase that gives you identical pixels, i.e. the specific area (of known size) that would tile seamlessly. you can imagine, that'll take some trial and error, i.e. looping over the phase space and calculating errors, finding that phase with least, or small enough, error. an entire area of phases may be identically good.
